# Migrating Wordpress blog from www.site.com to newdomain.com/blog

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration

I am planning on migrating a blog that is currently hosted at

`www.blog.com`

to a **subdirectory in a new domain** such as

`newdomain.com/blog`

So far I've seen several tips on how doing this and [in particular from Yoast (Joost) is helpful but not identical to my situation [1](http://yoast.com/move-wordpress-blog-domain-10-steps/).

Any suggestions?

The main steps on Joost's article are as follows:

[1 ] Edit wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.newdomain.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.newdomain.com');
```

[2 ] Use the Search and Replace plugin to replace old URLs

[3 ] Update .htaccess to

```
Redirect 301 /blog/ http://www.newdomain.com/ // <== note this is NOT my situation
                                              // I likely need the reverse
```

However, this won't address my particular need, in which a different change in .htaccess and wp-config.php may be necessary.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has some RewriteRules that it wants to use in an .htaccess file. It should look something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I think that all you need to do is take this and place it in an .htaccess file in your document root (where http://www.newdomain.com/ is). If you don't have any special rewrite rules or options in your .htaccess file, you could just move the file out of /blog/ and into /. You *don't* want these rules in both places.

Then in wordpress' admin panel (you'll need to go here: http://www.newdomain.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php ) there are 2 fields, one for `WordPress address (URL)` (this should say http://www.newdomain.com/blog/ ) and one for `Site address (URL)` (this should say http://www.newdomain.com/ ). And I think that's all you need to do.

If you are using custom themes you may want to double check any absolute URIs you have in the headers/footers/etc.

There's some more information about doing this here: [Giving Wordpress It's Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that you need to create an index.php in your document root. In the link above, under the section **Using a pre-existing subdirectory install**, you need to follow the steps to create an index.php. You only need 2 lines.

As for the code-igniter/wordpress conflict. You may need to get the 2 rules to jive with each other, and that may not be so easy to do. You either have to move code-igniter's rules into their own directory or use `RewriteCond` to make sure they don't step on each other. For example, adding a `RewriteCond !/index.php` so wordpress' rewritten URI won't get re-rewritten by code-igniter's.

Comment: thx @jon very helpful - as above `/blog` will contain the WP install - there will be other folders  like `/forum` that will be running from a Codeigniter install on this same domain - so I don't think I can use your rewrite rule in `/` since that will apply to the entire domain, it needs to apply only to `/blog` where WP is. Would that change the syntax of your rule above?

Comment: Just stick an empty .htaccess file in `/forum`. Or just put `RewriteEngine Off` in it. The rules in the document root won't apply to /forum/

Comment: OK - it's that I already have an .htaccess at `/` that rewrites Codeigniter's URLs so if I put an empty one in `/forum` the root .htaccess will not take effect, and it has to

Comment: Forgot to mention you need to create an index.php in your document root. All of the steps are outlined in that link I provided. As for getting the 2 rules to work with each other, that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a clean install. Just export your blog posts as XML, and copy over the uploads.